# System of mean recurrence time

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, means

Consider the following Exercise

> Three out of $4$ trucks passing under a bridge are followed by a car, while $1$ out of every $5$ cars passing under that same bridge is followed by a
>   truck.
>
> a) Show that this is a transition matrix and write down the transition matrix.
>
> b) Compute the stationary distribution.
>
> c) What fraction of vehicles passing under the bridge are trucks ?
>
> d) Given that the last vehicle seen was a truck, how long does it take on average until the next truck is seen under that same bridge ?

**MY ANSWER**

a) If we denote by $C$ and $T$ the states, we have $$\mathbb{P}=\begin{pmatrix} 4/5 & 1/5 \\ 3/4 & 1/4 \end{pmatrix}.$$

b) We know that the stationary distribution can be find by $\pi=\pi \mathbb{P}$. Thus, $\det(\mathbb{P}P^T - \mathbb{I})=0$ gives us the solution.

c) Thus, $4$ out of $19$ vehicles are trucks in the long-term.

**QUESTION**

d) I do not know why my professor here solves the following system $$\begin{cases}\mu_C = 1+ (4/5)\mu_C \\ \mu_T=1+(3/4)\mu_C\end{cases}$$
where $\mu_T$ and $\mu_C$ are the mean returning times from $T$ to $T$ and from $C$ to $C$ respectively. I do not know where this system of equations come from.

The only formula I know for the **mean recurrent time** of an state is the following $$\mu_j =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{j,j}^{(n)}$$
where $f_{i,j}^{(n)}$ is defined as $P(X_1\neq j,...,X_{n-1}\neq j, X_n =j\, |\, X_0=i)$.

Comment: In part d) is the right-hand side of the first equation correct?  Should that be $\mu_T$ rather than $\mu_C$?  If not, is the second equation correct?

Comment: They are OK. No errors.

Comment: That's very strange.  The equations ought to have the same form, since the situations are symmetric.  I think either you or your professor made a transcription error.

Comment: Supposing that an error was made, do you have any explanation to where these formulas come from? Which is the actual question btw.

Comment: I'm working on an answer.

Comment: The professor introduced the system by saying: using the 1st step analysis and given the fact that we are in state T, we have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we denote by $\mu_i = \mathbb{E}[T\,|\, X_0=i]$ the returning time to state $i$, then we have that $$\mu_i = 1+\sum_{j\in S} \mu_j p_{i,j}$$ where in the sum we set $\mu_j=0$ if and only if the last state seen is $j$. Thus, in my case, we have

$$\mu_C=1+(4/5)\mu_C + (1/5) \cdot 0$$
$$\mu_T=1+(3/4)\mu_C + (1/4) \cdot 0$$

hence $$\mu_C=1+(4/5)\mu_C$$
$$\mu_T=1+(3/4)\mu_C .$$